# Confused about Virtual Base Class in C++

Tags: c++, virtual

As we all know, no matter how deep the derived level is, the "**virtual base class subobject**" will be initialized only once by the "**most-derived**" class during object construction rather than more than one times by the "**middle-derived**" class, this semantic of "virtual base" is guranteed and implemented by the compiler, however, when I study other member functions except the "constructors", I find that, the compiler does not treat them as constructors, i.e., it does nothing to prevent from calling the member function of virtual base class many times, here's the code:

```
class vb
{
public:
    void f(){cout << "vb::f"<<endl;}

};
class A: public virtual vb
{
public:
    int a;
public:
    void f()
    {
        vb::f();
        cout<<"A::f"<<endl;
    }
};
class B: public virtual vb
{
public:
    int b;
public:
    void f()
    {
        vb::f(); 
        cout<<"B::f"<<endl;
    }
};
class C: public A,public B
{
public:
    int c;
public: 
    void f()
    {
        vb::f();
        A::f();
        B::f();
        cout<<"C::f"<<endl;
    }

};

// test example
int main()
{
    C a;
    a.f();
}
```

I test this code segment in Visual Studio 2008, and the result is:

vb::f

vb::f

A::f

vb::f

B::f

C::f
However, the desired result is :

vb::f

A::f

B::f

C::f

My question is :

1. How to make the vb::f() to be called only once in the above situation?
2. Why do the implementors of C++ not support this semantic directly from the language level?

OK, I try my best to make myself understood, however, I'm not a native people o English, hope you understand what I mean and thanks for any respond!

Comment: you forget about main(), we don't know what you are testing

Comment: Oh, sorry for that, I've just editted it

Comment: The goal of a `virtual` base class is to only have *one* instance of the data; it does nothing special to methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When more than one derived class inherits virtualy from the same class, there will be only one subobject of that class inside the object of the most derived class. That means that it can be initialized only once - and it is done by the most derived class.

But that's only initialization. It does not mean, however, that only the most derived class can access the members of the virtual base.

The inheritance tree in your example is like this:

```
   vb
  /  \
 A    B
 \   /
   C
```

whereas without the virtual inheritance, it would be like this:

```
vb  vb
 |   |
 A   B
 \   /
   C
```

There's nothing special for `A` and `B` in either case, they both derive from a `vb` and can call its methods without a problem. In the second case, inside `C` a call `vb::f()` is ambiguous and an error.

Comment: Yeah, your answer solved my confusion, especially the sentence below: "There's nothing special for A and B in either case, they both derive from a vb and can call its methods without a problem"

Answer (score 2):

- As long as you do qualified method calls using `className::functionName(...)`, no overrides will be called.
- `virtual` inheritance does *not* make the member function of the base class `virtual`. Try calling just `f()` everywhere and then try again with the member function `f()` in `vb` changed to

  - a virtual: `virtual void f(){cout << "vb::f"<<endl;}`.
  - a pure virtual: `virtual void f() = 0;`

Answer (score 1):

A method is going to be executed the number of times it is going to be called. You cannot stop that. whereas, constructor is special method which is called *only once*. Hence compiler has special semantics for constructor and cannot have such semantics for all methods.

What the virtual base class does here is that it allows you to call `vb::f();` **without ambiguity** from `class C`. Similarly, if there was some member variables in `vb` they would also be initialized only once.

If you remove the virtual keywords you wont be able to call `vb::f();` from `C` like that.

Comment: Yeah, I know what you mean.